# Edge browser is blocking Office-Helpers-Js library from closing authentication dialog after getting the token

Tags: excel, office-js, office-js-helpers

Inside an Excel add-in, I obligate the user to authenticate himself against an Azure AD app using the Office Helpers Library. When the add-in is launched, I invoke the "authenticate" function of the Authenticator instance, it opens the Login Dialog and finishes the login process with no problems, the issue is when the token is returned with the redirection, the Authenticator does not retrieve the information from the Href and close the dialog, instead it gets stuck in a blank page window.

I am using the version: 1.0.2 of Office Helpers from a CDN

here is the code:

```
 /// register Azure AD 1.0 endpoint using
    authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth(clientId, tenant, {
        responseType: 'token',
        redirectUrl: window.location.origin + "/Home.html",
        resource: resourceId
    });

    // First Login
    authenticator
        .authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD)
        .then(function (row_token) {
            // Azure Token 
            var token = new AccessToken(row_token.access_token, row_token.expires_at, row_token.expires_in, row_token.provider, row_token.session_state, row_token.state, row_token.token_type);
            var decoded_token = jwt_decode(row_token.access_token)
            client_email = decoded_token.upn;
            Office.context.document.settings.set("client_email", decoded_token.upn);
            access_token = row_token.access_token;
            Office.context.document.settings.set("access_token", row_token.access_token);
            expires_at = row_token.expires_at;
            Office.context.document.settings.set("expires_at", expires_at);
            Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
            var expires_in = row_token.expires_at - new Date() - 5000; // 5000 is five seconds before the token expires.
            setTimeout(function () {
                authenticator.tokens.delete(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD);
                authennticateUser();
            }, expires_in); // recall the current function when the token expires
            active_session = true;
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);  
}
```

the issue has occurred after the latest update of office (by 18/08/2019), it seems like Microsoft is officially abandoning the IE and considering Edge, on the IE there were no issues and the authentication worked perfectly, but now on Edge, it is failing as described earlier.